# Há como "resumir" os elseif's?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2

Em meu projeto do CakePHP, existem dois campos de dropdown para fazer uma pesquisa no banco de dados, ambos como string's. Preciso adicionar mais dois campos (ambos datas). No código abaixo (controller), utilizei 4 if's para fazer a verificação dos campos, quando eu adicionar os campos de datas, precisarei criar mais muitos if's ou há outra maneira mais facil?

RegitroHorarioController.php

```
$horarios = array();
        $cliente_id = (isset($this->request->data['RegistroHorario']['cliente_id']) ? $this->request->data['RegistroHorario']['cliente_id'] : null );
        $usuario_id = (isset($this->request->data['RegistroHorario']['user_id']) ? $this->request->data['RegistroHorario']['user_id'] : null );
        if($cliente_id != null && $usuario_id != null){
            $horarios = $this->RegistroHorario->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array('User.id' => $usuario_id, 'Cliente.id' => $cliente_id),
                'order' => 'RegistroHorario.data_fim DESC'
            ));

        }elseif($usuario_id != null && $cliente_id == null){        
            $horarios = $this->RegistroHorario->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array('User.id' => $usuario_id),
                'order' => 'RegistroHorario.data_fim DESC'
            ));
        }elseif($usuario_id == null && $cliente_id != null){
            $horarios = $this->RegistroHorario->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array('Cliente.id' => $cliente_id),
                'order' => 'RegistroHorario.data_fim DESC'
            ));
        }elseif($usuario_id == null && $cliente_id == null){
            $horarios = $this->RegistroHorario->find('all', array(
                'order' => 'RegistroHorario.data_fim DESC'
            ));
        }
```

View:

horarios_gerencia.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('RegistroHorario', array('class' => 'form-horizontal bucket-form', 'autocomplete' => 'off')); ?>
                            <div class="col-lg-3">
                                <?php echo $this->Form->select('RegistroHorario.cliente_id', array(null => 'Todos') + $clientes, array('empty' => false ,'div' => false,'label'=>false, 'class' => 'form-control m-bot15', 'width' => '10'));?>
                            </div><div class="col-lg-3">
                                <?php echo $this->Form->select('RegistroHorario.user_id', array(null => 'Todos') + $usuarios, array('empty' => false ,'div' => false,'label'=>false, 'class' => 'form-control m-bot15', 'width' => '10'));?>
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Buscar" />
                            <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao que pude ver, as condições modificam apenas o valor do `conditions`. Sendo assim, você pode setá-lo separadamente desta forma:

```
$conditions = array();
if ($cliente_id != null) $conditions["Client.id"] = $cliente_id;
if ($usuario_id != null) $conditions["User.id"] = $usuario_id;

$horarios = $this->RegistroHorario->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => $conditions,
    'order' => 'RegistroHorario.data_fim DESC'
));
```

Comment: Funcionou, valeu!!

Comment: Assim como em minha pergunta anterior, eu marcaria como útil, porém ainda não tenho 15 pontos para fazê-lo.. Quanto possuí-los marcarei, até mais